# In building my app in android studio, it will take time to build the gradle

Tags: android

How to make faster so that i can build an app even more faster?

and this my libraries for my app

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
//compile 'com.github.nisrulz:qreader:1.0.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.matthew-tamlin:sliding-intro-screen:3.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle has recently published the [Improving the performance of Gradle builds](https://gradle.github.io/performance-guide/) guide. Make sure to go over the document and follow the suggestions to improve the build times.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio requires good specification for hardware for smooth and efficient run.though i feel it to be at times,there are various work around's to make it feel improved.

the link below describes the method on how to make your android studio run faster [Make your Android Studio faster](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/08/how-to-make-android-studio-fast.html)

Comment: hmm i have a laptop that has a good spec for android studio, but as the time goes by, my android studio running slow.